# How can i copy directly a struct which is in pointer array of structs to another in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, strcmp

I need to directly copy a value from `array` to `array2` which is a pointer array to use pointing `organ` values. And in this code, i have used `memcpy` function but it didn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct organ{
    char *name;
};

struct human{
    struct organ *org;

};

void main(void){
    struct human*array = malloc(sizeof(struct human));
    array[0].org = malloc(sizeof(struct organ));
    array[0].org[0].name= malloc(6);

    struct human*array2 = malloc(sizeof(struct human));
    array2[0].org = malloc(sizeof(struct organ));

    strcpy(array[0].org[0].name, "lungs");
    printf("array name: %s\n",array[0].org[0].name);
    memcpy(&array2[0].org[0], &array[0].org[0], sizeof(struct organ));

    free(array[0].org[0].name);
    free(array[0].org);
    free(array);

    printf("array2 name: %s\n",(array2[0].org[0].name));

    free(array2[0].org);
    free(array2);
}
```

What did i made wrong? How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: The `memcpy()` line is dubious — it sorta works because `sizeof(struct organ) == sizeof(struct organ *)` in this code, but it certainly doesn't in general.  That line then copies the pointer in `array[0]` to `array2[0]`, which is more or less OK.  You then free data from `array` — that's OK, except that you're freeing the data that parts of `array2` are pointing at too — so the final `printf()` and the `free(array2[0].org];` lines are both invoking undefined behaviour.  You have to think hard about which structure owns which pointer — and if pointers are shared, how to keep track of that.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Is there any solution to do this copy processing directly ?

Comment: Since I'm really unclear on what you're trying to do, I'm not sure how to advise you properly.  You're using structures which aren't clear (you don't record the size of the arrays in the structures, for example).  Most organs are not all that long; you'd make your life easier if you included the array in the `struct organ { char name[MAX_ORGAN_NAME_LEN]; };` for example.  You also need to stipulate what you expect to happen if you copy a pointer from one structure to the other; are you transferring ownership, or did you mean to make a copy of the original data?

Comment: Oh, and on closer inspection, I think your `memcpy()` line means that the data allocated to `array2[0].org` is leaked.  You could achieve the same effect as your `memcpy()` line using `array2[0].org = array[0].org;`.

Comment: Are you aware of POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)?  Are you allowed to use it?  It'll make your life easier if you are.  Not that it is hard to emulate it: `char *str_dup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len); return dup; }` should do the job.

Comment: I didn’t know but this function can be useful. Thanks for your answers

Comment: @JonathanLeffler maybe you misread (or maybe I did...), but the memcpy seems correct to me and is equivalent to `array2[0].org[0] = array[0].org[0];`  . The problem is because the block allocated by `malloc(6);` is freed and then read

Comment: @M.M: I'm willing to believe I could be wrong — fried brain.  I don't have working Valgrind on a Mac at the moment.  I don't use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` most of the time, and certainly not in this context.  And I'm too lazy to switch to a machine with a VM, or connect to the Linux boxes with Valgrind running; it's Thanksgiving, and I'm giving thanks that it's not my problem.  I'm still not sure what the objective of the code fragment is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplification of the problem as in your code:

```
struct organ a, b;
a.name = malloc(6);
strcpy(a.name, "hello");
b = a;
free(a.name);
puts(b.name);
```

Your code uses `memcpy`,  but `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);` is practically the same as `b = a;` so I have used the simpler syntax in my example.

The problem is that there is only one call to `malloc`. Both `a.name` and `b.name` point to the same memory block. You free that block and then try to output its contents.

Perhaps what you want to do is to make `b.name` have its own memory block. This means you need to call `malloc` again, the `=` operator (or the `memcpy` function) does not call malloc.

For example in my code, change the `b = a;` line to:

```
b.name = malloc( strlen(a.name) + 1 );
strcpy(b.name, a.name);
```

---

In other words, the procedure for a so-called "deep copy" of a `struct organ` is not the same as the procedure performed by the assignment operator.

I would recommend that you make a function for performing a copy of `struct organ` that behaves in the way you want; and call that function instead of using the assignment operator or `memcpy`.

You could also do the same for copying of a `struct human`.

Comment: actually i know what is "deep copy", i just wonder that can i copy a struct directly which is held from a struct pointer array. Is it possible ?

Comment: @okydoky it does not make a difference whether the struct is "held from a struct pointer array" or not. You can decide whether you want a shallow copy or a deep copy